# Prevent loading image from appearing until form is complete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm building a site which requires the client clicking a submit button. This site includes HTML select menu's and input fields.

This information is then submit to a php file which then passes the data onto a MySQL database.

I've added some code to enable a loading image when the submit button is clicked. But currently, the user can click submit without filling in the form and the loading message appears as well as a message telling the user to enter data into the missing fields.

What I would like, is for the loading message to ONLY appear once the form has been filled out and when the data is being passed the PHP file.

I've crudely mocked this up in a JSFiddle below to better explain what I'm saying:

[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/jackanyon/fevzct3g/1/)

JSFiddle throws up a POST error obviously, but on my site obviously the data is posted and that error doesn't exist, so ignore it.

HTML:

```
<form onsubmit="myButton.disabled = true; return true;">
 <label for='name'>
  Please Enter Your Name:
 </label><br>

<input class="label" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Click/Tap here..." required><br><br>

<label for='urgency'>Urgency</label><br>
<select type="select" name="urgency" select id="urgency" required>
  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please specify an urgency...</option>
  <option value="1">1 - Least Urgent</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select><br><br>

<span>
  <button type="submit" name='myButton' value="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
  <button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button><br>
 </span>

<div id="loader" style="display:none;"><br>
    <label>
      Please Wait...
     </label>
  <img src="ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading" />
</div>
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){
$('#loader').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do not wire up the submit button. Instead use the submit event
2. do not use submit as id or name
3. use the id of the button if needed

---

```
$('#formID').on("submit",function(e){
  var empty = false;
  $("input:required",this).each(function() {
    if (!$.trim($(this).val())) {
      empty=true;
      return false; // leave
    }    
  });
  if (empty)  {
    e.preventDefault(); 
  }
  else {
    $('#loader').toggle();
    $("#myButton").attr("disabled",true);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could handle the toggling of loading images on the submit event (which is probably where you do your AJAX'ing):

```
$('form').on('submit',function(){
    $('#loader').toggle();
});
```

The submit event won't fire until the form fields are valid.
You will have to toggle it "off" somewhere else, fx. the "success" and "error" callbacks of the AJAX-function.

Hope it helps.